# How can I remove special characteres from expect?

Tags: bash, scripting, expect

So I'm using the next `expect` script in order to get the running-config of a switch and then save it to a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 9
set username [lindex "foo"]
set password [lindex "bar"]
set hostname [lindex "1.2.3.4"]

spawn ssh -q $username@$hostname

expect {
  timeout { send_user "\nTimeout!\n"; exit 1 }
  "*assword"
}

send "$password\n"

expect {
  timeout { send_user "\nWrong password\n" ; exit 1 }
  "switch-00>"
}

send "enable\n"

expect {
  "switch-00#"
}

send "show running-config\n"
log_file -noappend log.txt

expect {
  -ex "--More--" { send -- " "; exp_continue }
  "*#" { log_file; send "exit\r" }
}

send "exit\n"

close
```

It works as it should except for this:

```
--More--^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H
```

which is appearing in log.txt every time "--More--" gets printed.

It's not an issue to remove "--More--" later on using bash but if I do:

```
grep "^H" log.txt
```

there's no output, so I cannot remove it as it doesn't match.

I was trying to find a way to not output special characteres with `expect` if possible but didn't find any, so I'm asking here in case anyone knows.

A solution using bash would help me aswell but using `expect` is prefered.

Comment: Can't you set the `configure terminal length 0` so that you don't get `--More--` in the output ?

Comment: Nope, it's a Lenovo switch, seems not to have such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the bash `tr` utility. From the `man` page

```
NAME
tr -- translate characters

DESCRIPTION
The tr utility copies the standard input to the standard output with sub-
situation or deletion of selected characters.

SYNOPSIS
tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
tr [-Ccu] -d string1

-C     Complement the set of characters in string1, that is ``-C ab''
       includes every character except for `a' and `b'.

-c     Same as -C but complement the set of values in string1.

-d     Delete characters in string1 from the input.

To Strip out non-printable characters from file1.

tr -cd "[:print:]\n" < file1   # This is all you need.
```

Comment: Yup, it worked but it converted the whole file into just one line, any idea on how to keep it as it was?